# Firebase Firestore shows collection on console for emulator app but not for physical device

Tags: firebase, flutter, google-cloud-firestore

I'm trying to implement messaging for my app with firebase firestore. The issue is:

On Emulator:

- I can send message from userA to userB.
- I can see the sent data on firestore console.
- I can logout from userA and login to userB, the message is still on chat box. Everything looks fine.

On real device:

- I can send message from userA to userB.
- But can't see any data on firestore console.
- I can logout from userA and login to userB, the message is still on chat box. This also looks fine on device.

On other real device:

- I can login as userA/userB, but can't find the previous messages.

It looks like:

- firestore is not getting my data from real devices.
- the data is staying on device ?? (then why I see the data even after changing the user or re-opening the app).
- separate database for every device. But the data is on device only!!

Code:
service clas:

```
class ChatService{
  final log = logger(ChatService);
  final CollectionReference userRef = FirebaseFirestore.instance.collection('users');

  saveUser(User user)async{
    await userRef.where('id', isEqualTo: user.id).get().then((value)async{
      if(value.docs.isEmpty){
        userRef.add(user.toMap());
        log.i('user added.');
      }else{
        log.i('user already exist: ${value.docs.first.data().toString()}');
      }
    });
  }

  static Stream<List<User>> getAllDoctors(int selfID) => FirebaseFirestore.instance
      .collection('users')
      .orderBy('id', descending: true)
      .snapshots()
      .transform(StreamTransformer.fromHandlers(
      handleData: (QuerySnapshot<Map<String, dynamic>> data, EventSink<List<User>> sink){
        List<User> users = [];
        data.docs.forEach((element){
          if((element.data()['role'] == 1 || element.data()['role'] == 2 || element.data()['role'] == 4) && element.data()['id'] != selfID){
            if(element.data()['role'] == 1){
              users.add(Doctor.fromMap(element.data()));
            }else if(element.data()['role'] == 2){
              users.add(Volunteer.fromMap(element.data()));
            }else if(element.data()['role'] == 4){
              users.add(Pharmacy.fromMap(element.data()));
            }
          }
        });
        sink.add(users);
        print(users.toString());
      }
  ));

  static Stream<List<User>> getAllUsers(int selfID) => FirebaseFirestore.instance
      .collection('users')
      .orderBy('id', descending: true)
      .snapshots()
      .transform(StreamTransformer.fromHandlers(
      handleData: (QuerySnapshot<Map<String, dynamic>> data, EventSink<List<User>> sink){
        List<User> users = [];
        data.docs.forEach((element)
        {
          if(element.data()['id'] != selfID){
            if(element.data()['role'] == 1){
              users.add(Doctor.fromMap(element.data()));
            }else if(element.data()['role'] == 2) {
              users.add(Volunteer.fromMap(element.data()));
            }else if(element.data()['role'] == 3){
              users.add(Patient.fromMap(element.data()));
            }else if(element.data()['role'] == 4){
              users.add(Pharmacy.fromMap(element.data()));
            }
          }
        });
        sink.add(users);
        print(users.toString());
      }
  ));

  static Stream<List<Message>> getMessages(int senderID, int receiverID) =>
      FirebaseFirestore.instance
          .collection('chats/$senderID/messages')
          .orderBy('time', descending: true)
          .snapshots()
          .transform(StreamTransformer.fromHandlers(
          handleData: (QuerySnapshot<Map<String, dynamic>> data, EventSink<List<Message>> sink){
            List<Message> messages = [];
            data.docs.forEach((element)
            {
              if((element.data()['senderID'] == senderID && element.data()['receiverID'] == receiverID) ||
                  (element.data()['senderID'] == receiverID && element.data()['receiverID'] == senderID)){
                messages.add(Message.fromJson(element.data()));
              }
            });
            sink.add(messages);
          }
      ));

  Future<bool> sentMessage(Message message)async{
    try{
      final senderMessageRef = FirebaseFirestore.instance.collection('chats/${message.senderID}/messages');
      final receiverMessageRef = FirebaseFirestore.instance.collection('chats/${message.receiverID}/messages');
      // update sender messages
      senderMessageRef.add(message.toJson());
      // update receiver messages
      receiverMessageRef.add(message.toJson());
      return true;
    }catch(e){
      log.e(e.toString());
      return false;
    }

  }
}
```

build.gradle:

```
  dependencies {
        classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:4.1.0'
        classpath "org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-gradle-plugin:$kotlin_version"
        classpath 'com.google.gms:google-services:4.3.10'
    }
```

app level:

```
dependencies {
    implementation "org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-stdlib-jdk7:$kotlin_version"
    implementation platform('com.google.firebase:firebase-bom:28.4.0')
    implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-analytics'
}
```

dependency:

```
  firebase_core: ^1.6.0
  cloud_firestore: ^2.5.2
```

I'm really stuck with this for days now. Please help if possible.

Comment: Did you tried on any other device like other phone ?

Comment: check if internet is working on emulator

Comment: I think you need VPN on real devices

Comment: I tried with 5 real device in my office. all of them was wifi(same for all) connected.

Comment: @Nasir debug the app and check the all exceptions and tell  whets wrong, or flutter run --verbose and share logs

Comment: I tried this way, It all looks fine. And the data goes to the console DB. but when I install it on my device, the data doesn't goes to firebase. I'm very confused. the debug log doesn't show me anything wrong.